# is it possible to place an element over flash that has wmode=window in chrome?

Tags: html, flash, iframe, bgiframe

I'm working on a page that has some ads on it. One of them loads in an ad with wmode=window. I don't have the ability to change that flash code. I need to put a modal box on top of that flash element, but every combination of using z-indexes and iframe shims has failed (both manually and using bgiframe). Is there a way to place html content on top of a flash element with wmode=window? I'm testing this in chrome so far... figuring if I can't at least get it to work there, it won't work anywhere.

Comment: heya im in australia, 5am, so im goin to sleep i will check tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way around it.

WMODE-window forces the browser to render the element on the very top layer, and it will overlap everything.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, i had done this before using php and Css, your right though i did use the index "z" properties in my CSS Sheets than i had used php divs to what your trying to do, i maned to get 3 transparent flash Movies on top of each other , it was a pain for me and not much documents on this at the time,

trial and error is your best go, i had deleted my old web server i had used this method for, if you get desperate i will have a look through backup drives, but it is possible so dont give up